# Trouble getting emails to send via php script/html form

Tags: php, html, email

I have created a simple html form to send an email using php. Currently whenever I try to send the info I just get redirected to my process.php page with and browser error (myserver.com unable to handle this request).

I have already tried sending a test email by making my php page just the mail() function and it does indeed work so it has to do with my code somewhere. I'm sure it's something simple so here is my code.

**HTML (contact.html):**

```
<!-- Contact form -->
<form id="form" action="process.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for='name'><span class='required'></span></label>
        <input id="Field1" type='text' name='name' placeholder='Type your Email Here' required/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for='message'><span class='required'></span></label>
        <textarea id="Field2" name='message' placeholder="Type a Message for us Here" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type='submit'>SEND MESSAGE</button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

**PHP (process.php):**

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {

    //Email information
    $admin_email = "test@mydomain.com";
    $email = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Email from contact form";
    $comment = $_POST['message'];

    //send email
    if(mail($admin_email, $subject, $comment, "From:" . $email)) {
        echo '<p>Success</p>';
        header('Location: contact.html');
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Error sending message</p>'; 
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Please fully fill out the form</p>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in the PHP code you have shared - You are missing `;` in the `$subject = "Email from contact form"` line.

Please see bellow -

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['message'])) {

    //Email information
    $admin_email = "test@mydomain.com";
    $email = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Email from contact form";
    $comment = $_POST['message'];

    // //send email
    if(mail($admin_email, $subject, $comment, "From:" . $email)) {
        echo '<p>Success</p>';
        header('Location: contact.html');
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Error sending message</p>'; 
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Please fully fill out the form</p>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Of course I missed a semicolon.. Made the necessary changes to code. The problem still remains so I'll update my post.

Comment: Never mind.. While fixing the syntax errors I accidentally made another. Got it working, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file for mail configurations.

open php.ini file

search "mail function" there

set SMTP to your server

set sendmail_from (sending mail_ID)

Comment: I currently don't have access to the file but I did try sending a test email using this script:

    <?php

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "test@mydomain.com";
  $email = "Test@test.com";
  $subject = "Is this working?";
  $comment = "Yep, it's working";
    
  //send email
  mail($admin_email, $subject, $comment, "From:" $email);
    ?>